# JS Plugins not registered

Tags: shopware, shopware6

This is something we never had in our test shops, but some live shops have this problem using our plugins: The JS plugins of an extension are not registered.

The elements to which the PluginManager register the js plugin is there, we checked. There is no error in the console. The js plugins are tested and working fine.

We did the following: Deaktivating extensions step by step and testing. After a while, our js plugins are registered. Activating the deactivated extensions step by step often is successfull, that means, after activating all extensions again, our js plugins are still registered. Sometimes this did not work and we have to repeat.
Which extensions we have to deactivate and activate seems to be random.

Something seems to be not working with the registration process. It only seems to be happening in SW 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're encountering an intermittent issue with JavaScript plugin registration in Shopware 6.5, which doesn't seem to follow a consistent pattern based on the extensions activated or deactivated. This can indeed be perplexing and might hint at a deeper, systemic issue rather than a problem with any specific plugin or extension.

Given the symptoms you've described, I recommend trying to rebuild the storefront assets. This process can sometimes resolve issues related to the registration and loading of JavaScript plugins by ensuring that all assets are correctly compiled and up-to-date. You can do this by running the bin/build-storefront.sh command from the root of your Shopware installation. This script is designed to rebuild storefront assets and could help in ensuring that your JS plugins are properly recognized and loaded across all your environments.

Here's the command you should run in the root folder of your Shopware installation:

```
bin/build-storefront.sh
```

After executing this command, clear your cache and test again to see if the JS plugins register correctly. If the problem persists, it might be worth looking into the console for any potential errors that could have been missed previously or checking the network tab in your browser's developer tools for failed requests that might provide additional clues.

Let us know how it goes!